# SQL injection and lot of database updates are visible

Tags: security, database

[image]My Drupal Website is possibly compromised through a SQL injection and lot of database updates are visible. How to avoid further SQL injection?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Advising on how you could secure an entire website is too broad for the Q+A format here, so this will need to be closed. Please have a look through the [help] to find out what kinds of questions are on-topic. Separately, you might find it useful to look through the [top questions in the security tag](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security?sort=votes&pageSize=50) - they may contain some useful information

Comment: Thank You Clive, do I need to ask the same question again with only saecurity tag?

Comment: No, please don't - this question isn't appropriate for this website, it's too broad in nature. It could never be answered objectively and completely, which is something that's required for good Q+A

Answer (score 1):

Install [Security Review](https://www.drupal.org/project/security_review) for maintaining security of your website. Or if you have custom modules, make sure form handling is done only via [drupal forms](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7).

Comment: I checked with this, each time do i need to login to my site? Is there any other method of avoid further SQL injection from people?

Comment: have you checked https://www.drupal.org/project/hacked ? to make sure there is no change to the core and contrib files ?

Comment: drupal.org/project/hacked is something which gives me the log report, but my requirement is people should not access DB and make changes without permission

Comment: can you be bit descriptive .. like what content was changed by which user .. Are you sure it was changed by anonymous user ? if yes then install module https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access

Comment: Above I have added an Image, hope this will figure out what exactly i need to work on. Please have a look

Comment: It's hard to figure out, as Clive told you.